# jQuery - Get all elements with class from current point on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to figure out how to get all elements matching a specific selector from a certain point forward in the DOM.

I have HTML that looks like this

```
<div class="attribute-filter-wrapper">
    <select class="build-item-attribute-filter">
        ...options...
    </select>
</div>    
<div class="attribute-filter-wrapper">
    <select class="build-item-attribute-filter">
        ...options...
    </select>
</div>
<div class="attribute-filter-wrapper">
    <select class="build-item-attribute-filter">
        ...options...
    </select>
</div>
<div class="attribute-filter-wrapper">
    <select class="build-item-attribute-filter">
        ...options...
    </select>
</div>
<div class="attribute-filter-wrapper">
    <select class="build-item-attribute-filter">
        ...options...
    </select>
</div>
```

I also have bound to the change event of the .build-item-attribute-filter class like so...

```
$(document).on('change', '.build-item-attribute-filter', function(e) {
     // function code here
});
```

What I want to do, is in the change event, get all selects that are NEXT and reset their value.  So if I'm on the second one and I change the value, the event will be triggered and the 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc selects will reset.  But the first and second will stay in-tact.

I thought I would use the jQuery nextAll() method, but I'm confused on it's usage.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or show example?

Comment: [the documentation for `nextAll` seems to cover this well enough?](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/)

Comment: It does. `$(this).nextAll().val(newValue)`

Comment: @Liam - my HTML has been updated.  I forgot that each select was in a div wrapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this using the nextAll() and map function of JQuery. Updated as per new html

```
 $(document).on('change', '.build-item-attribute-filter', function(e) {

        $.map( $(this).parent().nextAll(), function( sel, i ) {
             $($(sel).find('select')[0]).val("");
         });
});
```

Working example : https://plnkr.co/edit/nxMScu2g1qHbcwuVSKz7?p=preview

Same link for updated html as well.

Comment: I updated the HTML in my example does this still apply

Comment: `$($(sel).children()[0]).val("");` is going to be fragile. It'll work now but isn't very flexible if the markup changes

Comment: @Liam Thanks for pointing out. updated the answer to be more specific for child select element.

Comment: @Deep - Thank you!  You're answer is working perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery .nextAll() method,

Documentation : https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

EDIT : For updated question following could be the solution.

```
$(document).on('change', '.build-item-attribute-filter', function(e) {
   // function code here
   var parent = $(this).closest('.attribute-filter-wrapper');
   $(parent).nextAll('.attribute-filter-wrapper').each(function(){
         $(this).find('.build-item-attribute-filter').val("");
   });
});
```

Comment: @Liam you beauty.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/3mqnxhyr/#&togetherjs=4NyA004lc3):

JS:

```
$(document).on('change', '.build-item-attribute-filter', function (e) {
            for (i = $(this).parent().index()+1 ; i <= $('select').length; i++)
            {
                $('select').eq(i).val(0);
            }
        });
```

Html:

```
<div class="attribute-filter-wrapper">
    <select class="build-item-attribute-filter">
        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
        <option value="1">10</option>
        <option value="2">11</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="attribute-filter-wrapper">
    <select class="build-item-attribute-filter">
        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="attribute-filter-wrapper">
    <select class="build-item-attribute-filter">
        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
        <option value="1">3</option>
        <option value="2">4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="attribute-filter-wrapper">
    <select class="build-item-attribute-filter">
        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
        <option value="1">5</option>
        <option value="2">6</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="attribute-filter-wrapper">
    <select class="build-item-attribute-filter">
        <option value="0">--Select--</option>
        <option value="1">7</option>
        <option value="2">8</option>
    </select>
</div>
```